# Why does AVCaptureSession.stopRunning not stop?

Tags: ios, swift, avcapturesession

I have recently been onboarded onto an existing project at work which is written in Swift.

The `metadataOutput(_:didOutput:from:)` delegate function looks like this:

```
func metadataOutput(_ output: AVCaptureMetadataOutput,
                    didOutput metadataObjects: [AVMetadataObject],
                    from connection: AVCaptureConnection) {
        captureSession.stopRunning()

        if let metadataObject = metadataObjects.first,
            let readableObject = metadataObject as? AVMetadataMachineReadableCodeObject {
            print("\(readableObject.stringValue)")
        }

        ... // other code
}
```

Theoretically speaking, the `print` function should only print once; however, in the console, I can see that the output is printed several times.

Is there something that I am missing out here? I have created a barebones standalone scanning app, and it prints only once there.

Comment: "I have created a barebones standalone scanning app, and it prints only once there." This means that the problem is not caused by this part of the code, doesn't it?

Comment: @Sweeper definitely, but I would just like to seek out opinions on what else could I be possibly be doing wrong. Kind of a developer `blind spot` I suppose :)